# Xamarinでボタンを押した時に複数画面戻る方法

Tags: xamarin

階層のマスタなどを選択して行って、最後の階層で選択を確定した場合に、複数画面戻る機能を実装したいと考えています。

とりあえず今は下のように書いてしまっています。

```
// 3画面戻る
Navigation.PopAsync(false).Wait(1);
Navigation.PopAsync(false).Wait(1);
Navigation.PopAsync(false).Wait(1);
```

もっとうまいやり方がありそうな気がしているのですが、、ご存知の方がいらっしゃれば教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

基本的には`Navigation.PopAsync()`3回で問題ありませんが、`Task.Wait(1)`では完了が保証されないため、単に`Wait()`とするか

```
async void SomeMethod() // asyncを付加する
{
    await Navigation.PopAsync(false);
    await Navigation.PopAsync(false);
    await Navigation.PopAsync(false);
}
```

のように非同期メソッド化すべきです。

また遷移対象がルートページであれば、`PopToRootAsync`が使用できます。

もしくは事前に履歴を削除しておくこともできます。

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
    Navigation.PopAsync(false);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ナビゲーションのスタックから要素を削除できるですね。うまくいきました。

ただ、 `await Navigation.PopAsync(false);` を3回だと 
```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index が発生しました
```
となってしまいました。
原因は調べられていないのですが、、時間がある時にまた確認してみます。